# Threads in rqt ROS Python

Tags: python, multithreading, ros, rqt

I am designing a UI plugin for robot inside [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) using python. Basically, there is a button termed as 'Goto Home' button. I want to move the robot once this button is clicked. Please note that the robot moves whenever I click this button but GUI becomes unresponsive for a while, which is obvious by the way code is written. Please see the code snippet below:

```
import rospy
from robot_controller import RobotController

from qt_gui.plugin import Plugin
from python_qt_binding.QtGui import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, context):
        super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(context)

        # Give QObjects reasonable names
        self.setObjectName('MyPlugin')

        # Create QWidget
        self._widget = QWidget()
        self._widget.setObjectName('MyPluginUi')

        # Create push button and connect a function
        self._goto_home_button = QPushButton('Goto Home')
        self._goto_home_button.clicked.connect(self.goto_home)
        self._vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._vertical_layout.addWidget(self._goto_home_button.)
        self._widget.setLayout(self._vertical_layout)
        context.add_widget(self._widget)

        # Create robot object to move robot from GUI
        self._robot = RobotController()

    def goto_home(self):
        self._robot.move_to_joint_angles(self._joint_angles)
```

I want to implement a thread here. More preciously, how to call `self._robot.move_to_joint_angles(self._joint_angles)` using thread in rqt. Please note that I am using Python 2.7 in ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Please see below code snippet:

```
import thread
thread.start_new_thread(self._robot.move_to_joint_angles, (self.home_pose,))
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[`actions`](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) would be more appropriate for this.

> In some cases, however, if the service takes a long time to execute, the user might want the ability to cancel the request during execution or get periodic feedback about how the request is progressing. The actionlib package provides tools to create servers that execute long-running goals that can be preempted. It also provides a client interface in order to send requests to the server.